# RuntimeException: No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid

Tags: laravel, continuous-integration, laravel-5.1, gitlab-ci

I started to use Gitlab CI for my Laravel projects, and configured a project (https://gitlab.com/nasirkhan/laravel-5-starter). There is not much test cased but the project setup is ok. 
I used the same configuration for an another project but the build is failing and shows the following  error. The build url is https://gitlab.com/nasirkhan/laravel-5-boilerplate/builds/1105655.

`RuntimeException: No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.`

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan key:generate` in your terminal (in your project folder). There is an `APP_KEY` variable in your `.ENV` file which needs a key. This code gets generated by running the command above.

Answer (score 1):

> RuntimeException: No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

This error would only occurs if your test suite requires actual usage of the encrypter. To solve this issue you probably need to add a dummy APP_KEY or use a specific key to your application/package phpunit.xml.

Your phpunit should looks like this:

```
// ...

<php>
    <env name="APP_KEY" value="AckfSECXIvnK5r28GVIWUAxmbBSjTsmF"/>
</php>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the default cipher in **confing/app.php** is "**AES-256-CBC**" which needs a 32 character string. but the key is some random 16 bit key.

So, you can either set "**AES-128-CBC**" in your **config/app.php** or run the command to create new key

`php artisan key:generate`